# Skip number of footer lines in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, flatfilereader

I am using `FlatFileItemReader` to read a delimited flat file. While I could skip number of headers with field `linesToSkip`, I wasn't able to skip footers by number of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom line mapper, within which you can either skip by regex match or line number.

```
public class CustomLineMapper extends DefaultLineMapper<FieldSet> {
    @Setter
    private int totalItemsToRead;
    @Override
    public FieldSet mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        if(lineNumber > totalItemsToRead){
            return null;
        }
        return super.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
    }
}
```

Finally register the custom line mapper the FlatFileItemReader

```
CustomLineMapper lineMapper = new CustomLineMapper();
    lineMapper.setTotalItemsToRead(totalLinesInFile - numberOfLinesToSkipInFooter);

FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
// skip headers
reader.setLinesToSkip(linesToSkipInHeader);
// skip footer
reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
```

Comment: How to get the totalLinesInFile value. and what if I am using xml configuration

Comment: Good catch. Thanks

Comment: For me, it didn't work with extending DefaultLineMapper, i had to extends PassThroughLineMapper. And after that, perfect, thank you !