# How to skip footer in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch . I have to validate header and footer before processing . I am able to get header but not footer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip number of footer lines in Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278568/skip-number-of-footer-lines-in-spring-batch)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ItemProcessor, something like below;

```
public class DataProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String process(String line) throws Exception {
        if (line != null && line.contains("footer")) {
            return "Footer Found";
        } else {
            return line;
        }
    }
}
```